# Untrusted connection error on Chrome and Firefox when opening HTTPS websites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https

Since a few days ago - I believe it started after the Daylight Saving Time change - I can't open websites that use HTTPS connections, such as Yahoo, Facebook and Youtube, on Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. Internet Explorer opens them normally though, and I can also browse those sites on my tablet.

The message I get on Chrome is **Your connection is not private**, and Firefox says that **This Connection is Untrusted**:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

[image: Firefos screenshot]

I have checked my system time and date, and they are correct. I've also tried reinstalling both browsers and disabling my antivirus and some other programs, but that didn't change anything.

Using the `ipconfig /flushdn` command on a Windows command prompt window fixed it for a while, but some hours later I started getting those errors again.

Comment: Well sorry Paul I am not a English native speaking person so its the best I can do. If you cant help cause its so hard to read which it is not why did you reply?  Posted stuff before on other websites and people are helpfuel regardless of my writing but thanks anyways

Comment: Ok well thanks. But I still need help so can you help with my issue?

Comment: Well it certainly looks like a date issue.  Can you post a screenshot of `date /t` from the command line?

Comment: Its NOT a time and date issue..omg I have checked it over and over its set right. I think its a virus the security certificate says parents on patrol. Cant find anyhitng on it I have delted it still no good. Someone said the mcgruff safeguard is installed on my pc but its not I have checked everywhere one can check. I used to have it a couple of years abck but unistalled it. Besides if that was the case would internet exploer not do the same its only Mozilla and chorme that is doing it ever wince about a week now. THis is so frutrading I jut want to smash this drn thing to pieces.

Comment: Its NOT a time and date issue..omg I have checked it over and over its set right. I think its a virus the security certificate says parents on patrol. Cant find anyhitng on it I have deleted it still no good. Someone said the mcgruff safeguard is installed on my pc but its not I have checked everywhere one can check. I used to have it a couple of years abck but unistalled it. Besides if that was the case would internet explorer not do the same its only Mozilla and chorme that is doing it ever wince about a week now. Tsis is so frustrating

Comment: all the screenshots I have and sorry for double post it would not let me edit it  
http://imageshack.com/a/img907/6181/BnvABB.png                                     
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/473/3kUvib.png                                       
http://imageshack.com/a/img911/1132/nybof0.png                                             
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/3939/icfNTb.png                                       
http://imageshack.com/a/img911/2628/g33B2N.png                                       
http://imageshack.com/a/img907/8569/I4DAbo.png

Comment: It looks like you are using Parents On Patrol or some such. This is causing your problems.

Comment: @fireblazin You might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

So, if not the date, the problem is stemming from a parental control system called  [McGruff SafeGuard](http://www.gomcgruff.com/). This system provides it's own certifications so it can decrypt emails, and sites you visit **Even over HTTPS**. Because the certificate it is providing isn't working, any HTTPS site will not let you continue.

If this is installed on your computer I would recommend uninstalling it and trying to see if it works.

However if it is not on your computer, but on your network, contact your network Admin and alert them that this security system may be causing problems.

Hope this Helps!